# How to I solve the error? In svn email notification?

Tags: ubuntu, email, subversion

I have working from svn email notification, but it got the error, could you help for me?

(The command executes automatic send file for my mail, but now not sending.)

```
svn commit -m "[1] add some text in this file"
```

error:

```
Sending        test/test.txt
Transmitting file data .
```

I go to syslog:

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog 

Sep  4 13:16:42 dmayavanlo1 logger: Going to execute the email notification command
Sep  4 13:16:42 dmayavanlo1 sSMTP[3116]: Unable to locate smtp.gmail.com
Sep  4 13:16:42 dmayavanlo1 logger: sendmail: Cannot open smtp.gmail.com:587
Sep  4 13:16:42 dmayavanlo1 sSMTP[3116]: Cannot open smtp.gmail.com:587
Sep  4 13:16:42 dmayavanlo1 logger: Traceback (most recent call last):
Sep  4 13:16:42 dmayavanlo1 logger:   File "/home/bugzilla/mysvn/hooks
/mailer.py", line 1348, in <module>
Sep  4 13:16:42 dmayavanlo1 logger:     sys.argv[3:3+expected_args])
Sep  4 13:16:42 dmayavanlo1 logger:   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/svn/core.py", line 281, in run_app
Sep  4 13:16:42 dmayavanlo1 logger:     return func(application_pool, *args, 
**kw)
Sep  4 13:16:42 dmayavanlo1 logger:   File "/home/bugzilla/mysvn/hooks/mailer.py", line 105, in main
Sep  4 13:16:42 dmayavanlo1 logger:     messenger.generate()
Sep  4 13:16:42 dmayavanlo1 logger:   File "/home/bugzilla/mysvn/hooks/mailer.py", line 383, in generate
Sep  4 13:16:42 dmayavanlo1 logger:     group, params, paths, subpool)
Sep  4 13:16:42 dmayavanlo1 logger:   File "/home/bugzilla/mysvn/hooks/mailer.py", line 653, in generate_content
Sep  4 13:16:42 dmayavanlo1 logger:     renderer.render(data)
Sep  4 13:16:42 dmayavanlo1 logger:   File "/home/bugzilla/mysvn/hooks/mailer.py", line 963, in render
Sep  4 13:16:42 dmayavanlo1 logger:     self._render_diffs(data.diffs, '')
Sep  4 13:16:42 dmayavanlo1 logger:   File "/home/bugzilla/mysvn/hooks/mailer.py", line 1042, in _render_diffs
Sep  4 13:16:42 dmayavanlo1 logger:     w(line.raw)
Sep  4 13:16:42 dmayavanlo1 logger: IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

2) `tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log`

```
[Thu Sep 04 12:34:11 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.12] Could not fetch resource information.  [301, #0]
[Thu Sep 04 12:34:11 2014] [error] [client 192.168.1.12] Requests for a collection must have a trailing slash on the URI.  [301, #0]
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your log file, the first error is:

> Sep 4 13:16:42 dmayavanlo1 sSMTP[3116]: Unable to locate smtp.gmail.com

(all the other errors are a consequence). I suppose that the cause is a temporary network problem. Try

```
ping smtp.gmail.com
```

to see if you can now reach it. To avoid such kind of problem in the future, you should install a local SMTP server (e.g. postfix), so that mail can be queued in case of temporary network problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solve the error:

I am go edit the line for mailer.py, so I got this error

Everything remove mailer.py:

1)sudo rm -r /usr/share/subversion.

2)sudo rm -r /myrepository/hooks/mailer.py.

3)sudo dpkg --purge remove subversion.

ofter you re-install in subversion:

4)sudo apt-get install subversion-tools

5)sudo cp /usr/share/subversion/hook-scripts/mailer/ mailer.py /myrepository/hooks/.

change the wonership in mailer.py:

6)sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /myrepository/hooks/mailer.py.

Ofter you check your commit command email notification working.